Can I use an INA128 as a diferential amplifier?

I need to measure the voltage from a reference solar panel. We've calibrated a shunt resistor to produce a mV output, and we're using an 8-channel datalogger to record these values.
The solar panel has an internal connection between its solar cells in the  array as shown in the image. I cannot remove that internal connection.
Due to this internal connection, the datalogger is unable to read the values correctly because its channels are not independent; the negative pins are all connected. To address this issue, I am considering the use of an INA128 op-amp as a differential amplifier with independent power supplies to isolate the signals.
The recorded values are inconsistent, and the gain is not 1 (Rg = NC.)
Any idea what I might be missing here?


I wanted to share my power supply scheme with you. I used two Zener diodes to create a symmetric power supply because I was concerned that it might be the source of the error. As you mentioned, the input voltage has a range, which could indeed be the issue since I am trying to measure a signal between 0 and 35mV.
The datalogger screenshot is below


Rodrigo - Hi, Your "answer" (which didn't answer your original question, so it shouldn't have been posted in the box labeled "Your Answer") has been added into the question as an edit i.e. an update. || Unless you are writing the full and final answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself, with no further help needed) please don't use the "Your Answer" box below. Instead, edit the question to add new info, if required (unless that invalidates a genuine answer already given). This is an example of how Stack Exchange differs from typical forums.

(continued) If you have a response to an answer which would not be useful for anyone else except the person you're responding to (so using a comment would be appropriate) and you want it to contain an image then as you may have seen, comments don't display images inline. If you want to add an image link in a comment, you can use this technique. Note that the draft answer (or question) must not be submitted. The draft answer (or question) is used only to upload the image & is then discarded.

What would be the maximum potential difference between the 3 shunt resistors?

All absolute voltages must be defined for an isolation amp to a common ground logger.  This is unlikely to work otherwise.  Where does the PT100 go?

We calibrate the shunt resistor based on the voltage corresponding to an irradiance of 1000W/m². In this case, the voltage at 1000W/m² is 37mV. However, this value can increase depending on the solar irradiance. For example, at 1300W/m², the voltage is approximately 48mV. Let's assume the maximum voltage will be 50mV

I'm not using a PT100; that's just the channel configuration available for all input options they provide.

What you are proposing could work.  There are a few conditions.
Shunt resistor voltages should be within the input range of the in-amp.  For INA128 it's from (V-)+2V to (V+)-2V.  If the positive supply rail is +36V, and the negative supply rail is GND (i.e. single supply operation), then your input range would be from +2V to +34V.
Your bank of in-amps shouldn't be completely floating with respect to the solar panel.
The Ref terminals of in-amps should be connected to a low impedance node.  Usually it's ground.
update:
Channel 2 on the logger shows 16.7V .  I'll make a working assumption that it's the common mode voltage of the highest shunt (and differential mode is between 0 and 35mV).  The in-amp is powered with ±12.5V .  A 16.7V signal is outside of the input range of the in-amp.

I wanted to share my power supply scheme with you. I used two Zener diodes to create a symmetric power supply because I was concerned that it might be the source of the error. As you mentioned, the input voltage has a range, which could indeed be the issue since I am trying to measure a signal between 0 and 35mV.

Your zener diodes are directly across the 25V supply, which will break the diodes. You need some resistance to operate them as shunt regulators:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The above will afford you about 25mA of current in each rail, enough to power several INA ICs. The INA128 requires inputs that never get closer than 2V to each supply potential, so you can't apply potentials outside the range −7V to +7V, relative to the central 0V ground. This shouldn't be an issue, since three shunted PV cells in series produces a potential difference of \$35mV \times 3 = 105mV\$, and the common mode voltage for all of them will therefore be very close to zero. Even eight of them will never produce a common-mode potential over 0.3V.
The output will have similar constraints, being unable to swing beyond ±7.5V. If we use a gain of 100 (\$R_G=511\Omega\$), each INA should produce +3.5V maximum.
So, with input common mode potential near zero, and an output swing well within the supply limits, the INA128 should perform perfectly well. The arrangement might look like this:

simulate this circuit
I hope it goes without saying that the 25V supply source needs to be isolated from all other measuring equipment, since the ground being used here has a very different potential from that source's own terminals.

Thank you, Simon. Connecting the first negative pole to the reference was a great idea. I will try it out and let you know the results.
